# mvn azure-functions:deploy creates 'not valid storage account name'

Tags: java, azure, maven, azure-functions

I'm following this microsoft tutorial below and trying to deploy my azure function using the **mvn azure-functions:deploy** command. My function app name/artifactid is **ci-cd-demo**:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/azure-friday-java-in-azure-functions/

However,  I receive an error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-maven-plugin:1.4.1:deploy (default-cli) on project ci-cd-demo: ci-cd-demod9632762a is not a valid storage account name. Storage account name mu
st be between 3 and 24 characters in length and use numbers and lower-case letters only.
```

I logged into the azure portal and created a Storage account. I also did this manually through the Azure CLI in command line. The storage account is "cicddemo777".

It looks as if when I run **mvn azure-functions:deploy**  , the project cannot find the storage account , so it creates one and appends a bunch of numbers to the end of my function app name. I have the function app name , resource group, appservice plan and region variables in my pom.xml under the azure-functions-maven-plugin.

Is there a way to define the property variable for my azure storage account inside my project so I can successfully run the azure-functions:deploy command with this error?

Comment: Have you set something in pom.xml? On my side it is no problem. Also, you can use `func azure functionapp publish <FunctionAppName>` to deploy your functionapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Thanks for ennth's sharing. This error comes from changing of functionAppName.

(Since FunctionAppName need unique in all of the world when deployed, it will generate a string of numbers by default.)

**Original Answer:**

`mvn azure-functions:deploy` is mainly used for the first time, because the files it produces are not specified. It will It generates random resources, which is by design.

Have a look of this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-java-maven?pivots=java-build-tools-maven#deploy-the-function-to-azure

Use `mvn azure-functions:deploy` should not face problem. Have you set something in pom.xml? There must be no character like `-` in storage account name.

This is my pom.xml, and it is no problem:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.function</groupId>
<artifactId>ci-cd-demo</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Azure Java Functions</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>1.4.1</azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>
    <azure.functions.java.library.version>1.3.1</azure.functions.java.library.version>
    <functionAppName>ci-cd-demo-20200406102526581</functionAppName>
    <stagingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/azure-functions/${functionAppName}</stagingDirectory>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven.snapshots</id>
        <name>Maven Central Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven.snapshots</id>
        <name>Maven Central Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
            <version>${azure.functions.java.library.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.functions.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <!-- function app name -->
                <appName>${functionAppName}</appName>
                <!-- function app resource group -->
                <resourceGroup>java-functions-group</resourceGroup>
                <!-- function app service plan name -->
                <appServicePlanName>java-functions-app-service-plan</appServicePlanName>
                <!-- function app region-->
                <!-- refers https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/tree/develop/azure-functions-maven-plugin#supported-regions for all valid values -->
                <region>westus</region>
                <!-- function pricingTier, default to be consumption if not specified -->
                <!-- refers https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/tree/develop/azure-functions-maven-plugin#supported-pricing-tiers for all valid values -->
                <!-- <pricingTier></pricingTier> -->
                <runtime>
                    <!-- runtime os, could be windows, linux or docker-->
                    <os>windows</os>
                    <!-- for docker function, please set the following parameters -->
                    <!-- <image>[hub-user/]repo-name[:tag]</image> -->
                    <!-- <serverId></serverId> -->
                    <!-- <registryUrl></registryUrl>  -->
                </runtime>
                <appSettings>
                    <property>
                        <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
                        <value>~3</value>
                    </property>
                </appSettings>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>package-functions</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>package</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${stagingDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>host.json</include>
                                    <include>local.settings.json</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${stagingDirectory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                        <excludeArtifactIds>azure-functions-java-library</excludeArtifactIds>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!--Remove obj folder generated by .NET SDK in maven clean-->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>obj</directory>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In most cases, you should choose `func azure functionapp publish <FunctionAppName>` to deploy your function app. First, create a FunctionApp on Azure, and then deploy to this App. This is the doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#publish

Comment: Thank you. I used the starter project and changed the function app name (removed the numbers) so thats why it was producing the error. I ended up manually running the commands in the AZURE CLI, but I did try to deploy after and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: @ennth I have update my answer, can you [mark it as the answer](https://0730bowmanwindow.blob.core.windows.net/work/mark.png) to end this question? Thanks.:)